# <% this.Parameter %> inside quotes; ASP variable not getting displayed on page correctly when used inside quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, parameters, quotes

On my masterpage I have a meta tag, the value of which is changes page to page. This is my tag:

```
<meta name="Description" content="<%= this.MetaDescription %>">
```

However, the quotes seem to cause this value to be interpreted literally on the page; when I inspect the html of the page, it says "content='<% this.MetaDescription%>'" instead "content='[Value of this.MetaDescription]'"

How can I make it interpret the variable correctly when it's placed inside quotes?

Comment: Do you have a value for `MetaDescription` in your code behind class? I mean do you set a value for this property in your code behind class?

Comment: Yes I do, and I've made sure that my parameter is set correctly by stepping through it.

Comment: What type of variable is `MetaDescription`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
content=<%='"' + this.MetaDescription + '"'%>
```

If e.g. `this.MetaDescription` is set to `'SomeString'` in code-behind, then the following markup will be produced and sent back to the client:

```
content = "SomeString"
```

It seems like when the `<%= %>` operator is enclosed in quotation marks does not evaluate at all. Instead, what lies between the quotation marks is sent back to the client.